# Swift: Call function from another class

Tags: ios, swift, class

So while I do see other examples of this online. None of them seem to work for me. I am trying to unhide my PinPadView class by calling it from the ViewController. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    func initPinLogin() {
        //Display the Pin Pad object in App
        PinPadView.loadPinPad()
    }

}

class PinPadView: UIView {

    class func loadPinPad() {
        let pinPad:PinPadView = PinPadView()
        pinPad.hidden = false
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I have answered my question below. It was a newbie mistake, but for those who are having similar issues and want to see what I did, it is there.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of the object

```
let pinPad:PinPadView = PinPadView()
```

which you are un-hiding.

Instead reference the object which you want to hide from your VC class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the input. I have figured out what I was trying to do. I did not have to call the function from another class but rather create an outlet in the ViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var pinPad: PinPadView!
```

after I did that, I was very easily able to do this

```
func initPinLogin() {
    //Display the Pin Pad object in App
    pinPad.hidden = false

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try tis:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    func initPinLogin() {
        let pinPad:PinPadView = PinPadView()
        pinPad.loadPinPad()
    }

}

class PinPadView: UIView {

    class func loadPinPad() {
        self.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: `loadPinPad()` shouldn't be a class method. Also `loadPinPad` will be deallocated once `initPinLogin()` reaches it's end.